# Why am I getting `Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND localhost:8081` when executing `npm run serve` after upgrading to webpack 5.x?

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, webpack

I had to upgrade a Vue project with a webpack 4.x dependency to webpack 5.x. Before doing so I had the following in my `vue.config.js`:

```js
devServer: {
  port: 8081,
  public: process.env.PUBLIC_ADDRESS,
},
```

`PUBLIC_ADDRESS` was defined in a `.env.development` file like so:

```
PUBLIC_ADDRESS=localhost:8081
```

After upgrading to webpack 5.x `public` is no longer supported so I changed to host like so:

```js
devServer: {
  port: 8081,
  host: process.env.PUBLIC_ADDRESS,
},
```

But this doesn't work. Instead I get the error:

```
C:\repos\miqa\web_client\node_modules\webpack-dev-server\lib\Server.js:2472
        throw error;
        ^

Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND localhost:8081
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (node:dns:107:26) {
  errno: -3008,
  code: 'ENOTFOUND',
  syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
  hostname: 'localhost:8081'
}
```

Why is this?

Answer (score 1):

I'm sharing this because it took me an annoyingly long time to realize this was the issue  and I'm hoping to save someone else some time.

You literally want to post only the host name to `host` - in other words, don't include `:8081`. In my case this meant editing my `.env.development` file from:

```
PUBLIC_ADDRESS=localhost:8081
```

To:

```
PUBLIC_ADDRESS=localhost
```

If you aren't using environment variables to store the host name your final code might look like:

```js
devServer: {
  port: 8081,
  host: localhost,
},
```

Instead of:

```js
devServer: {
  port: 8081,
  host: localhost:8081,
}
```

So simple, so easy to overlook.